# LeetCode 284: Peeking Iterator

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> Given an Iterator class interface with methods: `next()` and
> `hasNext()`, design and implement a `PeekingIterator` that support the
> peek() operation -- it essentially `peek()` at the element that will
> be returned by the next call to `next()`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> list: [1,2,3].
>
> Call next() gets you 1, the first element in the list. Now you call
> peek() and it returns 2, the next element. Calling next() after that
> still return 2.  You call next() the final time and it returns 3, the
> last element.  Calling hasNext() after that should return false.
> ```
>
> Follow up: How would you extend your design to be generic and work
> with all types, not just integer?

#### Code

```
#include <vector>


class PeekingIterator : public Iterator {
    int next_num;
    bool num_has_next;

public:
    PeekingIterator(const std::vector<int> &nums) : Iterator(nums) {
        num_has_next = Iterator::hasNext();

        if (num_has_next) {
            next_num = Iterator::next();
        }
    }

    int peek() const {
        return next_num;
    }

    int next() {
        int curr_next = next_num;
        num_has_next = Iterator::hasNext();

        if (num_has_next) {
            next_num = Iterator::next();
        }

        return curr_next;
    }

    bool hasNext() const {
        return num_has_next;
    }
};
```

#### Reference

LeetCode has a template for answering questions. There is usually a class named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename. For this question, the template is:

```
/*
 * Below is the interface for Iterator, which is already defined for you.
 * **DO NOT** modify the interface for Iterator.
 *
 *  class Iterator {
 *      struct Data;
 *      Data* data;
 *      Iterator(const vector<int>& nums);
 *      Iterator(const Iterator& iter);
 *
 *      // Returns the next element in the iteration.
 *      int next();
 *
 *      // Returns true if the iteration has more elements.
 *      bool hasNext() const;
 *  };
 */

class PeekingIterator : public Iterator {
public:
    PeekingIterator(const vector<int>& nums) : Iterator(nums) {
        // Initialize any member here.
        // **DO NOT** save a copy of nums and manipulate it directly.
        // You should only use the Iterator interface methods.
        
    }
    
    // Returns the next element in the iteration without advancing the iterator.
    int peek() {
        
    }
    
    // hasNext() and next() should behave the same as in the Iterator interface.
    // Override them if needed.
    int next() {
        
    }
    
    bool hasNext() const {
        
    }
};
```

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/peeking-iterator/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/peeking-iterator/solution/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/peeking-iterator/discuss/)

Comment: What if you peek from the last element? `peek()` after the 3 has been returned. In your case; it'd keep returning 3, but it should be null.

Comment: how to implement a working `Iterator` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Passing larger sized data in functions by `const &data` is a good idea since it does not make a copy. Note that when a parameter is passed by `const&`, the extra cost dereferencing and fewer opportunities for compile optimizing. You should do this typically when the data is large in size
- From your `next()` function

> ````cpp
>     int next() {
>         int curr_next = next_num;
>         num_has_next = Iterator::hasNext();
>
>         if (num_has_next) {
>             next_num = Iterator::next();
>         }
>
>         return curr_next;
>     } ```
> ````

What is the use of the `if (num_has_next)` branch? You are returning a copy of `next_num` that was copied **before** any modifications, and since `curr_next` is not a reference of `next_num`, any changes to `next_num` will not effect `return curr_next`. I think what you might want to do is

```cpp
int next(){
    next_num = (num_has_next) ? Iterator::next() : NULL;
    return next_num;
}
```

[ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) 
Since @hjpotter92 has mentioned it,  calling `next()` or `peek()` on the last element should return `NULL`.

- Have a look at [templates in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/) if you want to work with multiple types.

Comment: @Emma I have just talked about the key parts of your solution, otherwise, the solution by itself is already pretty good :)

Comment: Note that you will have to set `next_num` to `NULL` in the constructor if you want to use this function `next()`.